# Cannot Install Force.com IDE from Market or Site with Juno or Kepler org.eclipse.update.ui 0.0.0 error

Tags: ide, eclipse, install

After downloading eclipse after opening, select Help - Install New Software - Available Software Sites

```
Site name: Force.com IDE  
location: http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42
```

Select Force.com IDE and Next either at the bottom of the window currently or just before finishing the install and error message displays stating:

> force.com ide 28.0.1.201309101331
>   (com.salesforce.ide.feature.feature.group 28.0.1.201309101331)
>   requires 'org.eclipse.update.ui 0.0.0' but it could not be found

This happens via the Eclipse site and with the built in marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs when the Eclipse package was not unzipped properly.  There are issues with the Windows built in decompression settings that can cause the folders/files within the package from properly decompressing.  To fix delete the Eclipse package that had been decompressed and use a program such as 7-zip to decompress the existing zip file.
Open Eclipse select Help - Install New Software - Available Software Sites and enter

```
Name:  Force.com IDE
location: http://media.developerforce.com/force-ide/eclipse42
```

This location works for both 4.2 and 4.3 and will allow for the installation for the app